# How to remove the expand arrow of files in the files tree in android studio

Tags: android-studio

This is just annoys me I'm trying to go to some file and it just expands every time

[image]

You see here the arrow when I'm clicking the file instead of going to the file it just expands it
[image]

So I want to remove this expand arrow